# summation involving Dirichlet eta-function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anybody direct me to pages on MSE questions relate to this sum.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)}\eta(n+1)$$

I am looking for the closed form.

We can split the above to
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\eta(n+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\eta(n+1)$$

where [$\eta(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) is the Dirichlet eta function.

This is how the above sum come about. The reason I ask about the above series is to answer another sum namely,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$

Here is a [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.233.540&rep=rep1&type=pdf) dealing only with sum of $arctan(x)$.

---

Given

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)x^{n+1}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\tag1$$
 if you sum $(1)$ like this,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)}\left(\frac{1}{1^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}-\cdots\right)\tag2$$
 you will end with 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)}\eta(n+1)=\ln\frac{2}{\pi}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\tag3$$

Comment: Your sums would be simplified slightly if you start them from $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: I don't know how $\eta$ behaves for large $n$. Are you sure the sums converge? Do you have some reason for thinking there's a closed form?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, doesn't $\eta(n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Barry, yes, but until I followed the link, I thought it was about the modular form known by the same name.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you edited Dirichlet into the text, but *Dedekind* into the title!

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaargh!